How to close the mobile menu on a blogger website without clicking the X
I'm using a free template on a blogger.com website and the mobile menu only closes when you tap the 'X'. A user would expect the menu to close when you tap some blank space underneath the menu.
Here's a live version of the template I'm using so you can see what I mean: https://infinity-soratemplates.blogspot.com/ (
This is the only code I can find in the template that could control the mobile menu toggle.
How can I extend this to include the blank space?
$(document)["ready"](function() {
"use strict";
    var a = $(window);
$(".full-height")["height"](a["height"]());
        a["on"]("resize", function() {
            $(".full-height")["height"](a["height"]());
        });
    $('#parallax-menu ul').clone().appendTo('.scrolling-mobile-menu');
    $('.scrolling-mobile-menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('scrolling-active');
        $('.overlay').fadeToggle(170);
    });

I haven't tried to edit any code yet, as I'm not sure how this works. Any help would be much appreciated.
